# Why I do not need to put string escape character while passing property in React Component

Tags: regex, reactjs

I was creating a custom component in React and the custom component accepts regex expression as props. Like this -

```
<CustoInput label='Email Id' width={{width:'50%'}} 
    regex='^[A-Z0-9]+@[A-Z]+\.[A-Z]{2,3}$'
    msg='*   Improper format'/>
```

Generally in javascript I would need to put an escape character and the expression should look like this if I pass this as a variable -

```
'^[A-Z0-9]+@[A-Z]+\\.[A-Z]{2,3}$'
```

But in react, when I pass props values like this, no escape character is required and it works fine.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `\` is an escape character for JavaScript string literals (and thus needs to be escaped to specify a literal backslash); while it has no special significance whatsoever in HTML (and is thus treated as any regular character). Conversely, you'd likely need to escape `&`, for example (as `&amp;`), which does not need escaping in JavaScript.

Comment: Thats a very interesting comment (Conversely, you'd likely need to escape &) from React point of view..did not think about it. However, considering I wrote the react function in javascript, should the javascript rule not have precedence?

Comment: I guess I got your point. The props are being passed along with HTML and not JS, so the JS rules dont apply?

Comment: "However, considering I wrote the react function in javascript!" - You did _not_ write it in JavaScript. You wrote it in JSX, which is a mishmash of JavaScript and basically XHTML, that gets compiled to JavaScript. Inside XHTML, XHTML rules. Outside XHTML, JavaScript rules (as you noted). Also note that interpolated values inside the XHTML bits (the stuff inside curlies) again go with JavaScript rules: `regex='{"^[A-Z0-9]+@[A-Z]+\\.[A-Z]{2,3}$"}'`.